# Are ther any setup features which disable the CDT C/C==Search in Eclipse (Neon3 4.6.3)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an existing C/C++ project which i am debugging using Eclipse Neon3 (4.6.3) with C/C++ CDT. I am trying to locate where a particular  type is declared and defined. I am using the Search->C/C++ dialog. If I search for the string "GtkAction" with the following parameters:

Search For: Any Element
Limit To: All Occurrences
Scope: Working set: Set to my src folder in the project with all subdirectories selected

This returns
Occurrences of 'GtkAction" in working set - (0 matches) in the Search Panel

'GtkAction ' is present with 20 occurrences in one file alone within the scope defined in the working set.

I have tried searching for several other strings (function names, variable names) where I know the string is present in a file within the scope and again get no matches.

I have followed the instructions in the documentation for performing this search but cannot see where my problem is.

Can anyone suggest where I might start to look for problems?

Comment: Does "Open Declaration" (F3) on one of those occurrences of GtkAction work (i.e. takes you to the definition)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem rebooted and restarted clipse and whatever was causing my problem disappeared and the search is now working fine